# Setting up a linear dependence equation for which a subset is the set of all solutions and Minimum Magnitude Solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying for my Linear Algebra and Multigvariable Calc Final and I don't understand how to do question 2 in this paper: http://web.stanford.edu/class/math51/tests/16aut-f.pdf

(answers here) http://web.stanford.edu/class/math51/tests/16aut-f.pdf

For part A, we are given a matrix "A": (notice columns are linearly dependent)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 &-4 \\ 
 3& 9 & -6\\ 
 4&12  & -8 \\ 
 5&  15& -10 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

And we are also give a vector $ \vec v_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
-1 
\\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$ 
and we are asked to find a set $V$ such that $\vec v_0 - \vec x , (\vec x \in  V)$ is orthogonal to all columns of $A$. What I did was to dot  $\vec v_0- \vec x $ with 1 column of $A$ since they are all dependent. 
This gives the correct answer. (see answers at the top)

However, for part b, I just have no idea how to set up the system $B \vec x = \vec c$.  For c I just need someone to explain to me projection onto something of more than 1 Dimension. I watched: 
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/lin-trans-examples/v/expressing-a-projection-on-to-a-line-as-a-matrix-vector-prod

and I still don't understand it. I also know there is a way to do it using $N(A) = C(A^T)^\perp$ and $N(A^T) ^\perp = C(A)$ but how do I apply it here.